# How do you know what a 3-variable equation represents geometrically or physically?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Example equation:

$$z^2+xy-2x-y^2=1$$

I know that equation represents a plane. Is there any easy way to tell what a 3-variable equation represents from just looking at it?

Comment: Not really.  This could be a point, sphere, ellipsoid, hyperboloid, paraboloid, pair of planes, single plane.  The standard procedure is to turn it into a matrix equation, find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix, then deal with the linear terms before making a decision.

Comment: Ah. This is much more complicated than I expected.

Comment: And Michael is only talking about those of degree 2.

Comment: If your equation is second-order, then you may use canonical form of its quadratic form. Analyzing eigenvalues of the quadratic form you may reason about geometrics in any dimension.